# Filter data by month in Node.js and Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

What is the Best approach in filtering data by month in MYSQL database and NodeJS backend?

I have all data in my results variabile which i'm parsing to ejs.

```
let sql = "SELECT * FROM test_results";
    exports.home = function (req, res, error) {
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) throw err; // not connected!
        connection.query(sql, function (err, results, fields) {
            if (err) throw error;
            res.render('home/index', {
                moment: moment,
                results: results
            });
        });
        connection.release();
        if (err) throw error;
    })
};
```

I have timestamps of every time there were data written in DB so now i need to get number How many rows were created in January, February ...

I tried things like this:

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM test_results WHERE test_date_time BETWEEN '2018-01-01 05:00:00' and '2018-01-31 05:00:00'", function(err, results, fields) {
```

and i did this for each month and then parsed data to ejs. But i don't think this is good approach. Also i need all results on client side so i can work with them so i don't know if there is a way to filter data with JS not in SQL query.

I tried to convert timestamps with moment and then filter with if statement but i didn't figure out how to do this.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simples approach that i see.

Maybe not ideal but should fit you're purpose.

And you only need to run one query. This should give desired result.

You can use [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) , [COUNT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html) and [month](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-month-function.php) built in MYSQL to do this task.

Here is example :

`SELECT  COUNT(id) as amount, month(test_date_time) as month FROM test_results GROUP BY month(test_date_time)`

And this is output example:

[image]

From response you can see that it give me result :

- in month number 8 i got 1231 records(amount)
- in month 11 only 2.

Hope this helps.